# Java Simulated Annealing Acceptance Probability

Tags: java, search, heuristics, simulated-annealing, fitness

I have a program implementing simulated annealing. I'm having a problem with the acceptance probability, probably due to my lack of understanding of why raising euler's number to the power of (energy - energy') is useful.

The probability is always over 1.0 (100%), even when the temperature is very low, making this effectively a random search. How do I fix my acceptance probability to a normal rate for sA (high chance of accepting a worse solution at the beginning, low chance towards the end)?

Here is the method code:

```
if (mutatedSolutionFitness > originalSolutionFitness) {
        return 1.0;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Original solution fitness: "+originalSolutionFitness);
        System.out.println("Mutated solution fitness: "+mutatedSolutionFitness);
        System.out.println("Temperature: "+this.temperature);
        final double chance = Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature);
        System.out.println("Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): "+chance);
        System.out.println();
        return chance;
    }
```

And here's the output a few times:

```
Original solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Mutated solution fitness: 0.5555555555555556
Temperature: 999998.000001
Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): 1.0000001111113395

Original solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Mutated solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Temperature: 999997.000003
Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): 1.0

Original solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Mutated solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Temperature: 999996.000006
Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): 1.0

Original solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Mutated solution fitness: 0.5555555555555556
Temperature: 999995.00001
Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): 1.0000001111116728

Original solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Mutated solution fitness: 0.4444444444444444
Temperature: 999994.0000149999
Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): 1.0000002222235802

Original solution fitness: 0.6666666666666666
Mutated solution fitness: 0.5555555555555556
Temperature: 999993.0000209998
Math.exp((originalSolutionFitness - mutatedSolutionFitness) / this.temperature): 1.000000111111895
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example output the probability will always `>= 1` as it's **usually** set to 1 if the new solution is better than the current one.

Following the classic original formulation (equivalent to yours; besides the if-else behaviour) available @[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) (Kirkpatrick et al):

- `P(e, e', T) =`

  - `1 if e' < e` (as outlined above)
  - `exp(-(e' - e) / T` otherwise
  - where:

    - `e`: current solution
    - `e'`: new solution candidate
    - `T`: temperature

Some examples:

- `T = 100000`

  - current: 0.666, new: 0.555

    - `1` as `e' < e`
  - current: ```0.555, new: 0.666

    - `~0.99999889`
- `T = 10`

  - current: 0.666, new: 0.555

    - `1` (T does not change that fact)
  - current: 0.555, new: 0.666

    - `~0.9889614`

So it still will do a complete random-search accepting every candidate as long as each new candidate is better. That's a design-decision taken. But when the candidates get worse than the current solution, the acceptance-procedure matters.

For other approaches / designs, you should be able to find a lot of resources. [Matlab seems to always accept better candidates too, but uses a different formula elsewise](https://de.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-simulated-annealing-works.html).